# $axios.onError is not a function

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I am using [nuxt community axios module](https://axios.nuxtjs.org).

And this is my plugin inside plugins/axios.js

Everything was working fine but now all of a sudden I get the error `$axios.onError is not a function`

Here is my plugins/axios.js

```
export default function({ $axios, store, redirect }) {
    $axios.onError(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 422) {
            store.dispatch("validation/setErrors", error.response.data.errors);
            return redirect("/login");
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    $axios.onRequest(config => {
        config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        config.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";

        store.dispatch("validation/clearErrors");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a weird issue so I went back to my previous project and used the exact versions of those packages and it worked!

I had to update package.json for the following packages from this:

```
"@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.5.3",
"@nuxtjs/axios": "^4.5.2",


// to

"@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.5.2",
"@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.3",
```

Comment: Only @nuxtjs/axios matters for your issue